# Start application from within Phonegap application

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm just getting started with Android applications, and I wondered whether it is possible to start another application from within my own app, specifically if my app is a PhoneGap app?

Thanks!

Comment: Any application or one in particular ?

Comment: Basically any application. I'm planning to build two applications that would be able to start each other. Is that possible?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of an intent maybe? Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=someAppID }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PhoneGap beyond having looked over the documentation once or twice, but there appears to be a [plugin](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins) to send arbitrary Android intents.

Comment: Yeah, I found that one as well. Will try it out tomorrow and see if that works :)

Answer (score 1):

on iOS you simply launch the custom url scheme. 
Not sure but would imagine there is something similar for Android.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on iOS, since I also wanted to know that ;-)